# Is using a static ninject container threads safe?

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, thread-safety, ninject

I am currently using a static ninject container that hold a reference to a ninject kernel which are configured to return new instances each time of specifics repositories or services classes in a SOA architecture. I am using it between different threads it is safe to use it this way? Please note this is not a web application, this is a console application that use Entity Framework as the persistence layer. If its not thread safe what do you suggest?

Comment: what do you mean by "thread safty" and why you are worrying?

Comment: I mean since there many threads that will be using the container to get new instances. It is safe to get access to this container from more than one thead at the same time. Can this cause problems?

Comment: Threads are somewhat good reasons to be worried. When problems arise its hard to control them.

Comment: I have recently found an issue with the ninject kernel Rebind method. It is not thread safe. Make sure you only bind your types once.

Comment: Thanks for mentionning. That the kind of stuff i wanted to know. Fortunally i don't rebind anything. I bind them once in a ninject module at the start of the app when i create the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that in your comment itself

" I mean since there many threads that will be using the container to get new instances"

so every thread is asking container to create a new instance of a type so the every time you will get a new state of an object so you are not fiddling with the states , i don't think any problem lies here.

Comment: That what i though. So basically danger arise only when you want to change state of an object? I though accessing would also cause problems depending on what you access.

Comment: sort of , if you use lock then also see if you really need them , what are the resources lock is using , what is the plan if a thread is not releasing a lock , what is a plan if 2 threads ends in "LiveLock" situation, how many cores are in the system ? Try to write non threaded design first then identify the portion which can be made parallel etc.